# Characterization of closed subspaces of $ L^2(R)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Natural way to find an example of banach spaces is to look at closed subspaces of Banach spaces. Initially, It was really hard to find examples of closed subspaces of $L^2(R)$. Then, my professor gave me this example.

For $ f \in L^1(R) \cap L^2(R)$ such that $\hat f(0)=0.$ Then closure( in $L^2(R)$) of translational invariant linear subspace containing $f$ is the closed subspace of $L^2(R)$.

Then the question arises, what are all closed subspaces of $L^2(R)$ ?

Can we characterize all closed subspaces of  $L^2(R)$ ?

I would like to know more examples of closed subspaces of $L^2(R)$, if you are familiar with them.

P.S. There is nothing special about $L^2(R)$, question is also applicable to $L^p(R)$. But $L^2(R)$ has nice properties ( Fourier transformation isometry).

Comment: As Charles Matthews remarks below, you really need to impose some extra conditions on your subspaces before it is reasonable to ask for a characterization. The clue is that your question is phrased in terms of $L^2(R)$ and not, say, $\ell^2$ of the free group on two generators; as abstract Hilbert spaces they are "the same", but in many contexts one is interested in extra structure that comes from the "particular" Hilbert space you start with.

Comment: A related example in a slightly different setting: consider $\ell_2({\mathbb Z}_+)$ where ${\mathbb Z}_+$ denotes the set of non-negative integers, and let $S$ be the backwards shift operator. Then one can characterize the closed subspaces of $\ell_2({\mathbb Z}_+)$ which are $S$-invariant; this is, essentially, Beurling's theorem, the mere statement of which already requires complex analysis and some single-variable function theory.

Answer (score 5):

What kind of characterization are you thinking of? There are plenty of closed linear subspaces in a Hilbert space $H$, and they really have no special extra structure coming from closedness and linearity. Closed linear subpaces have a Hilbert dimension and co-dimension, and this is the only invariant to distinguish two of them, in the  sense that, of course, if $W$ and $V$ have the same dimension and co-dimension, there is a unitary operator $U$ on $H$ mapping $V$ onto $W$. The set of all linear closed subspaces of $H$ has the structure of an analytic manifold (with connected components labeled by the above pair of cardinal numbers).

There are several characterization for closed linear subspaces, e.g. *$V\subset H$ is a linear closed subspaces iff $V= V^{\perp \perp}$*; and you may also like this: *$V$ is a closed additive subgroup of $H$, arc-wise connected by $\alpha$-Hölder paths, for some $\alpha > 1/2$.*

In the case of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, a question richer in consequences woud be: characterize the closed linear subspaces that are stable for additional operations, like translations, dilatations, positive part. A good reference for these questions is Rudin's *Real and Complex analysis.*

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say there is "nothing special" about $ L^2(R)$, which is a Hilbert space. Abstractly the structure of its closed subspaces (as orthocomplemented lattice, say) is the same as for any other separable Hilbert space of infinite dimension: there are a large number of them, and this structure is well-known in the subject of quantum logic. There is actually no great mystery about finding closed subspaces, since you can take any subset *S* and look at the vectors orthogonal to it.